# How to reuse the same tests to test different implementations?

Tags: python, unit-testing

My language is `python 3` and I am trying to understand how to use the same set of tests to test different implementations of the same algorithm.

So far I am looking at the built-in `unittest` and my impression is that I have to make some sort of a class hierachy: a class that inherits from unittest.TestCase and implements all the actual tests and several descendants from its class that each test particular implementations with the tests from the parent.

However, this is just my idea of how it should look like. Could you please tell me how to actually use the same set of tests to test different functions that implement the same algorithm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done this by writing tests in a class that does **not** inherit from `TestCase` and then writing multiple test classes that **do** inherit from `TestCase` **and** the tests, but either have a factory method or a class attribute of the class to instantiate:

```
class TestAnyImplementation:
    def testThis(self):
        obj = getImpl()  # call to factory method
        self.assertTrue(obj.isEmpty())

class TestFooImplementation(TestAnyImplementation,TestCase):
    def getImpl(self):
        return Foo()

class TestBarImplementation(TestAnyImplementation,TestCase):
    def getImpl(self):
        return Bar()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leave your tests unchaged if you `import` the different implementations with the same name. To test `impl1`, do

```
import impl1 as impl
```

in your test code. To test `impl2`, do

```
import impl2 as impl
```

Everything else can be left unchanged, if both `impl1` and `impl2` have the same interface.

**Edit:** You can wrap these import in an `if` clause and use a commandline parameter to select one.

```
chooseImpl = ... # get commandline parameter
if chooseImp == "impl1":
    import impl1 as impl
elif chooseImp == "impl2":
    import impl2 as impl
```

Using this approach you can don't have to change the test.

Comment: In this case I either have to make sure I am testing the correct implementation each time I run my tests, or I have to duplicate test modules for each implementation. Both scenarios I do not like, sorry.

Comment: I've edited my answer. But please don't just tell us what you *don't like* but what you have tried to solve the problem. Try to think for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use parameterized tests with your tested functions as a parameter.

For example, using `ddt` module for parameterized testing:

```
def sum1(list1):
    return sum(list1)

def sum2(list1):
    res = 0
    for x in list1:
        res += x
    return res

import unittest
from ddt import ddt, data

@ddt
class SumTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @data(sum1, sum2)
    def test_sum(self, param):
        self.assertEqual(param([1, 2, 3]), 6)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

In this example, you have two functions "sum1" and "sum2" implementing the same algorithm: summing of list elements. In your test class, you have only one testing method "test_sum" that takes the concrete summing function as a parameter. The two summing functions are specified as a list of values for a parameterized test.

You can install "ddt" with pip:

```
pip install ddt
```

Comment: thank you. However, in this case all the implementations will be tested once the test is run. In the inheritance case, one can separate the `TestFooImplementation` and `TestBarImplementation` into two separate files without duplicating the actual tests which are inside `TestAnyImplementation` and then run just the one that is required.

Comment: This requirement wasn't mentioned in the question. I naturally thought you wanted to test all your implementations. Of course, if you need more flexible solution, inheritance is the right way to go.